# A similar approach for LabelEncoder in sklearn.preprocessing?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, scikit-learn, data-science

For encoding categorical data like `sex` we normally use `LabelEncorder()` in `scikit learn`. But If I'm going to use `Tensorflow` instead of `Scikit Learn`, what is the equivalent function or methodology for doing such task? I know that we can do `one hot encoding` easily with `tensorflow`, but then it will create labels as `10` , `01`  instead of `1` , `0`.

Answer (score 1):

There is a package in TensorFlow called [tf.feature_columns](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/feature_column), that contain 4 methods to create categorical columns from your input data:

- categorical_column_with_hash_bucket(...): Hash the input value to a fixed number of categories
- categorical_column_with_identity(...): If you have numeric input and you want the value itself to be treated as a categorical column
- categorical_column_with_vocabulary_list(...): Outputs a category based on a fixed (memory) list of words
- categorical_column_with_vocabulary_file(...): Same as _list but reads the vocabulary from file

The package also provides lots more way of getting your input data to the model. For an overview, see this [blogpost](https://developers.googleblog.com/2017/11/introducing-tensorflow-feature-columns.html) written by the developers of the package.

Comment: Inlined more information directly asked by the question. The blogpost was written by the developers of the package.

Comment: What would be the best option to label encode the variable that is being predicted?